# Select Columns on group by sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dear Technical I need your Help

I have a table this have 2 column one is Series and 2nd is item 
like

```
Series   item
1       apple
2       apple
3       apple
5       apple
6       apple
7       apple
8       apple
```

I want to result as

```
from    to     item  total
1       3      apple   3
5       8      apple   4
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It'S Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most databases have a function called `row_number()` that generates sequential numbers.  It can be used in this case.  The difference between this function and your `Series` is constant for a group:

```
select min(Series) as "from", max(Series) as "to", item, count(*) as num
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by item order by Series) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by (Series - seqnum), item;
```